# How can I evenly distribute a list of objects to an array of other objects

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting

I am making a card game using the console. One class, the distributor, contains a method called `public void DistributeCards(Player[] players)`.

This method takes in a player array as argument, which contains all instantiated player objects. The distributor class also contains a field called `List<Card> deck = new List<Card>()`, as well as the property `Deck`.

How can I evenly distribute the cards in `distributor.Deck` to the decks of all players in the given array? The amount of players given in the array is restricted to either 2 or 4 (to evenly split the deck).

This is what I tried so far:

```cs
public void DistributeCards(Player[] players)
{
    int amountOfCardsTodistribute = Deck.Count / players.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfCardsTodistribute; i++)
    {
        players[0].Deck.Add(Deck[i])
        Deck.RemoveAt(i)
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Distributor distributed deck.");
}
```

^ In this example, the given amount of players was 2. As I was hoping, half of the deck of the distributor was given to players[0].
When I copied the code in lines 6 and 7 and pasted it below the original (, changing the players index, ) I got an error (NullReferenceException). The index was not within the list's possible indexes.

Specifically, I am asking for a structure that is able to distribute the amount of cards in a deck (52) among an even number of players <= 4, so that every player obtains the same amount of cards in his/her deck. The deck of the players is an empty list of cards, so they have unlimited capacity. The hand will be a seperate Card[]-array within the players. I hope this is enough to clarify. Feel free to ask questions if certain things are unclear.

Comment: _"How can I evenly distribute the cards in distributor.Deck to the decks of all players"_ -- please be more specific. Define "evenly". If a deck has 52 cards and you have 3 players, what should be done with the extra card? What does it mean for a player to have a "deck"? How is this different from a "hand"? Please provide a [mcve] that shows the code closest to working that you were able to achieve, as well as a clear, detailed explanation of what that code does, how it's different from what you want, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. To clarify: I restricted the possible amount of players to be either 2 or 4. Every player is supposed to obtain the same amount of cards. The hand of the player isn't implemented yet, but it's supposed to be a second Card[]-array with the length of 5. The hand array is going to be drawing one card from the deck each turn. Each player will also be forced to set at least one card every round. I am also going to update the question to clarify.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I built a poker game in java, and a blackjack game in c# before, you are best modelling your deck as a `Stack`, this better models how a real deck of card works. You are best reading up on `Stack`, [stack documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.stack?view=net-5.0). You will find alot of card style games have modelled decks as stacks, this should make it easier for you to find help online. I have wrote dealing functions for table of players in poker which works off the `Stack`.

if you mean evenly as in each player has the same amount, then we can do something like this

```
int amountOfCardsTodistribute = Math.Floor(Deck.Count / players.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < amountOfCardsTodistribute; i+=amountOfCardsTodistribute )
{
    Player[i].Cards.AddRange(Deck.Skip(i).Take(amountOfCardsTodistribute));
}
```

if we need to remove the cards from the deck and evenly 'deal' the cards,

```
while(Deck.Count > players.Length)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Players.Length; i++) 
    {
        Player[i].Cards.Add(Deck.ElementAt(0));
        Deck.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second solution worked just like I envisioned it. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome - please upvote correct answer!

Comment: Im sorry for replying so late... My reputation is too low.